# Ionic 4 tab: remove current page before pushing new page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using **Ionic 4** and tab layout.

I have one tab page with QR Code Scanner. Hence the the page is set to transparent as below

```
<ion-content padding color="transparent">
  <ion-item lines="none" class="top-content">

    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-label text-center no-margin>
            Scan QR Code to start
          </ion-label>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

and have following interface

[image]

The second tab displays a list of items and thus have **pull-to-refresh** on the page. The code is

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Item List</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="refreshList($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content>
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>

  <ion-card color="primary" (click)="showAction(1)">
    <ion-card-content>

      <!-- item content -->

    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

But on pulling the page, it shows transparent background from the first page where the QR Code scanner has opened the camera and thus on pulling it shows camera output.

[image]

**How can I close or hide page before opening a new page?**